# Firing a gun instead of a bullet

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons

> NOTE - To the person who edited the title. I was not asking about recoil
>   in the sense of the gun travelling in the opposite direction to a
>   *bullet*. Please read the question carefully. There is no bullet - just
>   a fixed rod that is set in concrete. Effectively therefore the Earth is the bullet and might as well be considered to have infinite mass. As has been pointed out in the answers, the result is actually
>   a mortar and specifically a spigot mortar. (I didn't know this before
>   I asked).

**Firing guns at friendly forces**

We are besieged in the castle. Friendly forces have arrived to attack the besiegers from the rear. Unfortunately our friends are terribly short of weapons although they have plenty of ammunition but no guns. On the other hand we have plenty of guns but are rapidly running out of ammunition.

Therefore we wish to project guns over the heads of the besiegers to our friends where they can be loaded and used in battle.

**Method**

The gun is loaded with a bullet-less cartridge and the gun-barrel is slid over a fixed rod that closely fits into it. The rod is angled at 45 degrees to the horizontal and set in concrete at the other end  The gun is fired via a thread that pulls its hair-trigger and breaks as soon as the gun flies off towards its target.

**Question**

Is shooting a gun in this way even possible or would the barrel burst? If so, how do I calculate how far the gun would travel? I am not clear how to convert the range of a bullet fired from a gun (with recoil) into the range of a gun fired from an immovable 'bullet'. Will any spin imparted to the gun owing to it not being symmetrical affect the range adversely?

All assistance gratefully received.

Comment: Any search engine will give you plenty of pages with the ballistic equation, if you just make the effort to search.

Comment: Rig up a catapault; tie your guns in a bundle; load and launch

Comment: Of course there's an [xkcd for this](https://what-if.xkcd.com/21/)

Comment: You are in effect loading the gun with a projectile hundreds of time heavier than the projectile it was designed to shoot. In real practice, double-loading the gun was considered to shorten its life, triple-loading was dangerous, and quadruple-loading suicidal. (As for how to compute: $m_b v_b^2 = m_g v_g^2$, hence $v_g = v_b m_b/m_g$, where $m_b$ is mass of the ball, $m_g$ is the mass of the gun etc. The magical non-bursting gun will start with about 1% of the muzzle velocity of the ball, or about 3 m/s. [It will travel one meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).)

Comment: Even setting aside the conservation of momentum problem AlexP provides, you still have an issue that even experienced model rocket builders struggle with, keeping the balance between center of mass and center of aerodynamic pressure.  You are essentially launching a crooked rocket tail-end first.  It's going to spin and tumble and deviate who knows what direction.  So let's say you surround your rifle with a cardboard cylinder, nose cone, and fins to try to overcome this.  Well, now you've added to your mass, and are still nose-heavy.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a whacky Bollywood physics principle. Might work in another universe. Not in this one, tho.

Comment: Even if this worked, the weapons are unlikely to be usable after they impact the ground at the other and of the ballistic arc.  Broken stocks, damaged mechanics, etc.  This falls into my "launching an ICBM horizontally" class of questions.  Can you do it? Probably - but the bad outweighs the good.  But, to answer your question, we're missing details.  (a) how far the guns must travel, (b) the height of the wall, (c) the location of the wall along the horizontal path, (d) the weight of the guns, (e) the composition of the guns.

Comment: @Separatrix - That xkcd is a completely different question but thanks anyway.

Comment: The title aCVn gave this question is much more clear than the title you want, and the XKCD is *very much* on-topic.  You're basically turning guns into bottle rockets and using their recoil to loft them over enemy troops.  If you provide the data I asked for, this is a fairly straightforward physics question.

Comment: Although I am starting to wonder what rule of your world you're asking about....

Comment: With a spigot mortar, you are only correct that the guns would not be *bullets* in the sense that they would be called *bombs or shells* (maybe grenades). However, functionally there would be no difference - somehow a pin will hit a primer which will ignite the propellant and then the projectile will launch. This is not the method described in your question (under **Method**) which is describing using recoil to launch a gun backwards due to the force of the expulsion of the projectile (or, with a blank or "bullet-less cartridge", explosion of the propellant). Either way - gun will be ruined.

Answer (score 5):

This would not generally be practical. The chamber is designed to handle the impulse of making the bullet start moving into the barrel. That is the inertia of the bullet and forcing the bullet into the rifling. In your concept we can assume that the "rod" would be designed to have roughly the same friction but the inertia would be that of moving the entire gun. Guns are generally significantly heavier than the bullets they are designed to launch specifically to prevent recoil from moving the gun too much.

So the gun would probably break even if you figured out how to not destroy the rifling or the barrel or how to have the gun **land** safely. Both of which would take time to solve you probably would not have.

Also since the guns are not designed to be launched they have inferior aerodynamics so the range would be very bad for the force. And given that the range would start as a fraction of what a bullet from the gun would have... Well, if your friends are that close just shoot the enemy in between and have them bring you ammo.

These issues are probably solvable with time. You are talking about an improvised mortar here so if you make an improvised projectile with the gun safely contained within, combine propellant from multiple rounds of ammunition and launch this from an improvised mortar, you can probably launch this over the enemy.

But you probably should not. You have more pressing needs for you time and precious ammunition. You should go for something more efficient.

First, shooting excess ammunition to the castle would be more effective. Ammunition is more compact and robust than guns are, so if you are going to shoot something that is what you should shoot. You'd still need improvised mortar and containers but, well, you have people without guns out there, right?

Second, if you want to move something without breaking it, something like a hot air balloon or even a kite is much more practical solution than shooting it and hoping it survives. Even if you do not have an acute shortage of propellant.

Third, generally shoot the enemy not your allies. Ammunition is better used against the enemy unless your soldiers are proud graduates of the imperial stormtrooper markmanship academy. Shooting the enemy is what bullets were designed for, using them for anything else will be less efficient, and will be a bad idea unless you have more ammunition than you need.

Comment: The people in the castle are so short of powder that they can't afford to shoot the enemy with bullets. That's why they want to send the guns to their friends who have all the ammo but no guns. I'm not sure how you could shoot ammo to the castle without any guns and of you did they would receive spent ammo.

Answer (score 3):

The principle you describe is the [spigot mortar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortar_(weapon)#Spigot_mortar). So it works in theory, but not -- as Ville Niemi pointed out -- in practice.

- A [36-pounder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-pounder_long_gun) was called that name because it fires a ball that was 36 (French) pounds. For all practical purposes, 36 pounds.
- The barrel was roughly 200 times the weight of the ball.
- The ball would fly about 3,700 metres.

It would be incorrect to simply multiply the range by the weight ratio, but it should give you a feeling that the barrel won't go very far on any practical powder charge.

Comment: It should be noted that this (the way a spigot or any mortar works) does not resemble the method described by the OP. It does answer the question title in the sense of "make the gun into a shell then put it on a mortar that would set off the primer and propellant launching the gun over the wall". Converting a gun into a bullet or shell (including fins and weight re-distributions if you wanted to aim at all) would pretty much guarantee problems trying to use them after (not to include the problem with hitting the ground at high velocity)